# Storing data in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to store in mongodb something like this:

```
{ "devices" : [ { "idDevice" : 1, "type" : 0 }, { "idDevice" : 2, "type" : 1 } ] }
```

I'm using mongoose with node.js, in the mongoose schema I'm declaring "devices" variable as follows:

```
devices: [{ type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: false }]
```

And when I store a new device with my code, I'm getting this:

```
"devices" : [   {   "idDevice" : 1,     "type" : 1 } ]
```

Someone knows why are these spaces between "[   {   "?

Comment: Your question is why there are extra spaces in the output? How are you displaying it? It's not going to affect the data storage in anyway.

Comment: Can you show us the code for printing/logging output in your node.js program?

Comment: it's not affecting the data storage and when I get devices from my node.js app it is working fine (extra spaces doesn't matter), but in mongo shell I'm using db.collection_name.find() and then it shows the extra spaces.

Comment: Spaces don't mean anything. Don't trouble yourself with it. If your question was also about IDs-you can get those simple numeric IDs by using some plugin like: https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-auto-increment